# rtorrent pauses torrents and cant resume

Tags: linux, rtorrent

rtorrent pauses torrents after a while on its own. Server is running 3 rtorrents, only one does this, but I can not figure out why. It is not stopping seeding on a ratio, it pauses even torrents with 0.00 uploaded.

I can not press start and they will run again, i need to remove them and upload .torrent file again. Here is my rtorrent.conf

```
    # Global upload and download rate in KiB. "0" for unlimited.
download_rate = 0
upload_rate = 2000

directory = /home/rtor/uploads/
session = /home/rtor/session2/

schedule = watch_directory,1,1,load_start=/home/rtor/watch2/*.torrent
schedule = untied_directory,1,1,stop_untied=
schedule = low_diskspace,5,60,close_low_diskspace=5000M


# Enable the default ratio group.
ratio.enable=

# Change the limits, the defaults should be sufficient.
ratio.min.set=600
ratio.max.set=1200
ratio.upload.set=2G

# Changing the command triggered when the ratio is reached.
system.method.set = group.seeding.ratio.command, d.close=, d.erase=

port_range = 21040-21045
check_hash = no
encryption = allow_incoming,enable_retry,prefer_plaintext

hash_read_ahead = 8
hash_max_tries = 5
hash_interval = 10

encoding_list = UTF-8
scgi_port = localhost:5001
#scgi_local = /tmp/rutorrent3.socket
schedule = chmod,0,0,"execute=chmod,777,/tmp/rutorrent3.socket"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pause"? Are they actually marked as stopped, or just inactive? If they're just inactive, it might be because you run out of peer slots, upload slots, open file slots or whatever.